# Solaris 10, sed insert #include <iostream> before first #include statement

Tags: bash, awk, sed, solaris-10

On Solaris 10, I have several source files similar to file1.cpp, as given below:

```
// file1.cpp
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
void func() {
. . .
}
```

I would like to insert `#include <iostream>` before first `#include` (if any): thus, the file would become:

```
// file1.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
void func() {
. . .
}
```

In case there is no include e.g.

```
// file1.cpp
void func() {
. . .
}
```

This will become:

```
// file1.cpp
#include <iostream>
void func() {
. . .
}
```

However, if the file already contains `#include <iostream>`, the insertion of another `#include <iostream>` would be ignored. Thus, if we have,

```
// file1.cpp
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>
void func() {
. . .
}
```

It will remain same, i.e.

```
// file1.cpp
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>
void func() {
. . .
}
```

My attempt:

```
bash-3.00$ cat TRYIT
#!/bin/bash
echo \#include \<iostream\> > x$$
for  i in `find . -type f -name "*.cpp"`
do
 if  ! grep -s "\#include \<iostream\>" "$i"  > /dev/null; then
    sed  "/\#include/r x$$" "$i" > "$i".bak
    mv "$i".bak "$i"
 fi
done
rm x$$
```

But this does not work as per my requirement, please suggest.

Comment: Are you looking to write a program to do this or looking for a linux command?  If it is the latter I do not think it is really appropriate for SO as there should be a general linux answer somewhere.

Comment: @NathanOliver a bash shell script that would take care of the different scenarios as mentioned

Comment: @NathanOliver I don't see where you're getting Linux from.  The question specifically asks about Solaris 10.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Gues I should have said *Nix

Comment: Nice specification for your problem, but oops, you forgot to include your attempt to solve the problem. Recall that S.O. isn't a free coding service, it is to help people fix problems in the code. Please update your Q with your best attempt to solve your problem. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter edited with my attempt

Comment: You should probably break up the tasks. Identify files *without* `<iostream>`. For example, `grep -vIR <iostream> *.cpp | cut -f 1 -d ':' | sort | uniq`. That gets you a file list which need `<iostream>`.  The second part is trickier, and a real Bash man (or woman) will need to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works OK on Linux, and I believe it should work on Solaris.

File `xyz.c`:

```
/* First line must not start #include */
#include <stdio.h>
#define PERGATORY
#include <meniscus.h>

the real code
```

Command:

```
$ sed -e '1,/^[:space:]*#[:space:]*include/ { /^[:space:]*#[:space:]*include/i\
> #include <iostream>
> }' xyz.c
/* First line must not start #include */
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#define PERGATORY
#include <meniscus.h>

the real code
$
```

If you need to deal with files that have a `#include` at the start of the first line, it is fiddlier.  Without a change, you get `#include <iostream>` inserted before line 1 (what was wanted) and also before the first line after line 1 that starts with `#include`.  With GNU `sed`, you can use `0` in place of the `1` and it works well; referencing line 0 is not a POSIX standard feature and probably won't work on Solaris, though.

I'm not sure what's the best workaround without that — probably using `awk` instead of `sed` is the least difficult (and it works nicely for the first `#include` after the first line as well, of course — it is a more general solution):

```
awk '/^[:space:]*#[:space:]*include/ { if (done++ == 0)
                                          print "#include <iostream>" }
     {print}' …filename…
```

---

> What about if I want to have `iostream` as variable captured in `$NM`, i.e. `NM=iostream` set earlier in the script? How do I use `$NM` within the `awk`?

```
NM="iostream"

awk -v header="$NM" \
    '/^[:space:]*#[:space:]*include/ { if (done++ == 0)
                                          printf "#include <%s>\n", header }
     {print}' …filename…
```

The key point is the use of `-v variable=value` on the command line to relay the header name to the `awk` script, and then modifying the `print` into a `printf` to format the string correctly (remembering that a newline is needed).

Comment: The use of awk is nice, what about if I want to have iostream as variable captured in $NM, i.e. NM=iostream set earlier in the script and how do I use $NM within the awk in awk '/^[:space:]*#[:space:]*include/ { if (done++ == 0) print "#include <iostream>" } {print}' …filename…